# Best way to extract Key-Value Pairs from unstructured String?

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, text-extraction

Avoiding at most hard-coded rules for specific patterns.

I'm currently working on a similar project as AWS Textract, [link here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/textract/features/). I've been successful at extracting data from files, but in an unstructured way. Now, i'm trying to figure out, and in the best ways, how to get existing Key-Value Pairs from that bunch of information.

For example we have a text like that :

> In this document we will find different key and values like this id : 1 and that country : France with no specific punctuation and probably talking about how good is my health...

The extraction would be something like that :

```
id : 1
country : France
health : good
```

What i actually know is that Amazon use a "confidence" variable into extracting information from that kind of scenario, which i guess involve some machine-learning algorithm. In my case, i don't have that big of a database to learn from.

I'm pretty sure that there is an easier solution neither less flexible.

Comment: This is a natural language processing problem, which currently are best solved using machine learning algorithms. Even if you can come up with an algorithm that doesn't require *a priori* information, you would need to *validate*  the algorithm against some data.

Comment: Great use case! I have something similar too. Did you find a solution? Please share your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that [spaCy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy) library may be the the right tool for your needs. Check out the description on GitHub to figure it out.

It can be exposed to Node JS using [spacy-nlp](https://github.com/kengz/spacy-nlp/blob/master/README.md) package.

Comment: I'm going to try this right now. I'll tell you if it gives the right results.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192). If the tool or library is not free-to-use, please also mention this in your answer.